# Pass parent state to generic child widget

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, state, bloc

I'm building a flutter app, and I have built a customized AppBar widget for it. This appbar has a SearchBar widget, which calls whatever callback is passed to it onChange. Now, there are multiple screens that use this SearchBar, and each of them will do something different with the user input. But I've noticed that on each of the screens that use the appbar, I'd have to use a state to control the SearchBar inputted text. So, I'm trying to not have to create the state for every screen, and have a Widget that wraps my screens, and controls the input in it's state, and passes it's state down to the child I provide to this apps. This would be similar to React's Higher Order Components, which wrap another component and can pass props to it.

This seems to me like a good design pattern, but I don't know how to implement it. Since the child widget that I would pass to this second order component that would wrap my screens, won't be getting any info from it, the child is simply passed as a widget (note: the code is also doing other stuff, working as a general wraper to replace similar repetitive code in all of my screens):

```
class CustomScaffold extends StatefulWidget {
  final ScreenInfo appBarInfo;
  final Builder child;
  final Widget bottomBarApp;
  final Widget appBar;
  final EdgeInsetsGeometry padding;

  const CustomScaffold({
    @required this.child,
    Key key,
    this.bottomBarApp,
    this.appBar,
    this.padding,
    this.appBarInfo,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CustomScaffoldState createState() => _CustomScaffoldState();
}

class _CustomScaffoldState extends State<CustomScaffold> {
  String searchTerm = '';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            widget.appBar ??
                GradientAppBar(
                  title: widget.appBarInfo.label,
                  searchBar: SearchBar(
                    callback: (String input) {
                      setState(() {
                        searchTerm = input;
                      });
                    },
                    placeholder: widget.appBarInfo.searchPlaceholder,
                  ),
                ),
            Padding(
              padding: widget.padding,
              child: widget.child,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: widget.bottomBarApp ?? CustomBottomBarNavigator(),
    );
  }
}
```

I'm thinking that I could passa builder instead of a widget as the child, but I'm not sure how this would work. Also, I'm still learning bloc in general, so I'm not sure if it would be a good idea to use bloc for this. I'm guessing bloc's purpose is a little different, and would complicate this specific pattern.

Does this idea make sense? What would be the best way to implement it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could expand your state management solution to include BLoC, but if all you're trying to do is propagate data down the widget tree, then provider/riverpod is a more straightforward option.